# How would I restore Spotlight search to my menu bar? (10.7)

Tags: terminal, spotlight

For some inexplicable reason, I decided to delete (not hide) Spotlight from my Mac via a terminal command. I downloaded the 10.7.2 update, hoping it would fix this by redownloading Spotlight, but it did not.

This is what happens when you give an idiot access to the terminal.

For reference, I this is my menubar right now:

[image]

I tried [this method](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20091030173117381) to be sure I simply didn't hide the Spotlight icon.

Spotlight is still in the system preferences.

I am just interested in fixing this. I should note that I didn't reinstall the OS.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What terminal command did you run to delete Spotlight?

Comment: What did you initially do to "delete" Spotlight? And (other topic): Can you still search directly in a Finder window?

Comment: And what happens if you issue the shortcuts (keyboad commands) to initiate Spotlight (Cmd-Space and Cmd-Opt-Space by default)?

Comment: At this point, I don't remember. I know I deleted it, as I'm getting [this](http://cl.ly/CWrh) error.

Comment: patrix- no response when I press the default keyboard commands. As for Finder, I can still search there.

Comment: There is never a `/System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app`. Do you have a `/System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle`? If so, you've still got Spotlight on your computer, it's just hidden.

Comment: @NathanGreenstein Yes, that does exist.

Comment: What kind of Mac do you have? With what OS did it ship?

Comment: @Daniel I have a 2010 iMac, shipping with Snow Leopard, now on Lion.

Comment: Do you have a Time Machine backup from before you removed the search icon?

Comment: I didn't. I'll probably do a fresh reinstall, with all my documents backed up to Dropbox. I have very little data, so I should be fine. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Do you have a reference to Spotlight in /etc/hostconfig? Delete it and reboot.

Comment: I don't have a reference to Spotlight there.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that inverting your commands would do the trick. Try:

```
sudo mdutil -a -i on
sudo chmod 755 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search
sudo killall SystemUIServer
```

Comment: I did try that. Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

While there may well be a more granular approach, this should work (but will take a bit of time):

Step 1: Back up your machine to an external drive using Time Machine

Step 2: Boot holding <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to boot from the restore partition

Step 3: Re-install Lion

Step 4: Use Migration Assistant to reinstall your documents and applications from your Time Machine backup.

This should leave you with an intact system, but all your data and applications.

Comment: I will probably do that, I just wanted to avoid the reinstall process. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure there is a *better* solution than this, but it's a baseline.